# Get line with the next closest date to today from list Powershell

Tags: powershell

Sorry for a possibly simple question, but honestly I cannot form the right solution.

There is a list generated by the script, which contains information with time and name of the AD group, presented in the following format:

```
+----------------+---------------------+
|  ADGroupName   |       StartTime     |
+----------------+---------------------+
| AD-group-name1 |  15.7.2020 00:00:00 |
| AD-group-name2 |  18.7.2020 00:00:00 |
| AD-group-name3 |  21.7.2020 00:00:00 |
| AD-group-name4 |  22.7.2020 00:00:00 |
| AD-group-name5 |  23.7.2020 00:00:00 |
| AD-group-name6 |  24.7.2020 00:00:00 |
| AD-group-name7 |  25.7.2020 00:00:00 |
| AD-group-name8 |  26.7.2020 00:00:00 |
| AD-group-name9 |  30.7.2020 00:00:00 |
+----------------+---------------------+
```

The question is next: how to display one line from the list, which will include only closest next date to today´s date?

Thank you!

Update: Original code looks like this

```
cd 'E:\Program Files\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin'
Import-Module .\ConfigurationManager.psd1
cd T:\
$CollectionIDs = "id1" , "id2"
$date=[datetime]::Today.ToString('MM')
$month= $date.substring(1) 
$Outfile = "C:\temp\outfile.txt"
if (Test-Path $Outfile) {Clear-Content $Outfile}
foreach ($id in $CollectionIDs) { 
if ($id -eq "id1") { 
Get-CMMaintenanceWindow -CollectionId "$id" | Select-Object @{Name='ADGroupName';Expression={'\AD-group-name1'}}, StartTime | Sort-Object StartTime -Descending | ft -AutoSize | out-string | Add-Content $Outfile
}
elseif ($id -eq "id2") {
Get-CMMaintenanceWindow -CollectionId "$id" | Select-Object @{Name='ADGroupName';Expression={'\AD-group-name2'}}, StartTime | Sort-Object StartTime -Descending | ft -AutoSize | out-string | Add-Content $Outfile
}
}
$result = Select-String -Path $Outfile -Pattern ".$month." -SimpleMatch
Remove-Item $Outfile
$result -creplace '(?s)^.*\\', '
```

Comment: Can you show us the original script that produced that output? Solution might be different based on whether the `StartTime` values are preserved as `[datetime]` objects or whether they've been converted to strings

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for your question. I'd recommend four you to take the [Tour] and read at least [Ask] to set your expectations. SO is not a free code writing service. We expect you to make an own attempt to solve your problem and we will be happy to assist you with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like Mathas said in a comment, it's still now obvious if StarTime is a string or a datetime. So I created array of objects with StartTime as strings and added parsing. .

```
    $data=@(
        @{ADGroupName='AD-group-name1';StartTime='15.7.2020 00:00:00'},@{ADGroupName='AD-group-name2';StartTime='18.7.2020 00:00:00'},@{ADGroupName='AD-group-name3';StartTime='21.7.2020 00:00:00'},@{ADGroupName='AD-group-name4';StartTime='22.7.2020 00:00:00'},@{ADGroupName='AD-group-name5';StartTime='23.7.2020 00:00:00'},@{ADGroupName='AD-group-name6';StartTime='24.7.2020 00:00:00'},@{ADGroupName='AD-group-name7';StartTime='25.7.2020 00:00:00'},@{ADGroupName='AD-group-name8';StartTime='26.7.2020 00:00:00'},@{ADGroupName='AD-group-name9';StartTime='30.7.2020 00:00:00'}
    ) | foreach{[pscustomobject]$_}
    
    # fixed date just to create working example
    $today =  get-date -Year 2020 -Month 7 -Day 24

    # parse datetime strings, filter by today, sort, select first result
    $data | 
      select adgroupname,@{n='StartTimeParsed';e={[datetime]::ParseExact($_.StartTime,'dd.M.yyyy HH:mm:ss',[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)}} | 
      where StartTimeParsed -gt $today | sort StartTimeParsed | select -First 1
```

Comment: Sorry to you and Mathias for late respond from my side, yes, StartTime has a datetime format. And this works perfectly fine, thank you very much!